# Generic bounds with pre-generics raw types

Tags: java, generics, collections, jodatime

I've got a Collection with the element type of `<K extends Comparable<K>>` because it's ordered.

I'm trying to use Joda `LocalTime` with this collection - e.g. `MyCollection<LocalTime>`.  Unfortunately, apparently Joda is pre-generics; `LocalTime` implements raw `Comparable`.

I'm getting the compiler error

```
Bound mismatch: The type LocalTime is not a valid substitute 
for the bounded parameter <K extends Comparable<K>> of the type Interval<K>
```

I would expect this to work with just a warning, as it's quite possible to assign a raw type to a typed variable.

Why doesn't this work, and what can I do about it?

Here's a minimal code sample:

```
class Holder<K extends Comparable<K>> { }
class WTF extends Holder<LocalTime> { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a wrapper class around `LocalTime` which `implements Comparable<K>` and passes through all the method calls.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing in the interim.  Ugly as sin though, looking for a better solution!