# Why do Joda instants extend the raw type Comparable?

Tags: java, jodatime

Joda's [AbstractInstant](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html) interface extends the raw type `Comparable`, instead of `Comparable<AbstractInstant>`, which seems to violate [Java best practices](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=224). In particular, it means that I cannot use DateTime to parameterize a class like this:

```
class Foo<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    public int ct(T a, T b) {
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

It was my understanding this kind of class was perfectly valid (it certainly works with Double, etc.). To get it to work with DateTime, though, I have litter my own code with the raw type and suppressed warnings:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
class Foo<T extends Comparable> {
    public int ct(T a, T b) {
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221431/generic-bounds-with-pre-generics-raw-types) that suggests a workaround (wrapping the DateTime in another class for the purposes of comparison), but I don't see why that should be necessary. My question then is:

1. Does anyone know why Joda is extending a raw type, or
2. Is this a bug I should report to the library maintainers?

Comment: Just a note for those coming to this answer almost a year later: Joda 2.0 supports generics, so it address this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JodaTime is designed to work on Java 1.4, and so does not use any Java 5 features, including generics.

So yes, you need to add that boilerplate warning suppression stuff in some cases.

Comment: It's not "boilerplate warning suppression". I have to change the interface of a generic Comparable-based class, in violation of Java best practices.  If I did not have access to the source code for that class, I could not have done it.

Comment: @chrispy: OK, fair enough. The point is, you're stuck with it.